# Insert html module in the txt file

Tags: php, html, web, browser

I wanted to know how it was possible to transcribe an html form into a txt text file. I don't have much experience with the PHP language, however, by searching the internet I managed to put something up:

```
<?php

$file = "testo.txt";

$fp = fopen($file, "a");

fputs($fp, htmlspecialchars($_POST["nome"]) 
       . " " . htmlspecialchars($_POST["cognome"]) 
       . " ". htmlspecialchars($_POST["select"] . "\r\n");

fclose($fp);
?>
```

The problem is that as soon as I integrate the php file into html and send the form, the php file is opened in my browser and the text file is not created, does anyone know how to help me? 
This is the part of code in html:

```
<form class="form-login clearfix" method="POST" action="prova.php" enctype="text/plain”>
    <input type="hidden" name="dep" id="dep" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="dop" id="dop" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="evp" id="evp" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="mid" id="mid" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="rememberme" id="rememberme" value="">
```

if it is not possible to transcribe it in a txt file it is enough for me to have a way to export it without the user having to click anything, in fact I also tried with "mailto" but asks the user to send the email.

Comment: But you don't have `nome`, `cognome` and `select` in your form, so turn on error reporting to see if there is any errors

Comment: Instead of the format inputs I had put the names of the labels, I tried inserting the names of the inputs that are inside the form but the same thing always happens, that is, as soon as I click on the "enter" button the php file is opened on the browser

Comment: You are redirected because your `action` redirects browser to PHP file that is then executed. That's how it works. All values in `$_POST` is from `<input name=""`> where "name" is same as key in _POST

Comment: Also your input fields are empty and hidden, so in file there will be appended just empty space

Comment: I tried to eliminate "hidden" but it doesn't change anything, I tried with an even simpler html code but it doesn't work. What should I put into action if not the php file? I have the html code on one page and the php file on another which is called with the action